# Redirect whatever.net to whatever.com without explicitly writing "whatever" in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I have a web app, that will be running on many different domains (and possibly subdomains). Each domain/subdomain will be available as both `.net` and `.com`. I want to redirect every request of `.net` to `.com`.

Example:

```
www.whatever.net -> www.whatever.com
www.sub.whatever.net -> www.sub.whatever.com
whatever.net -> whatever.com
sub.whatever.net -> sub.whatever.com
somethingelse.net -> somethingelse.com
...
```

For various reasons I'd like to have only one nginx.conf file that works for every installation, so I can't write something like:

```
server {
    server_name .net;
    return 301 $scheme://whatever.com$request_uri;
}
```

Because this works just for the installation that's under the *whatever.net*/*whatever.com* domains. So I tried:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^(?<name>.+)\.net$";
    return 301 $scheme://$name.com$request_uri;
}
```

But this does not work, it capture every request, not only those coming from the `.net` domain, and (on chrome at least) the result is that the content of the address bar become: `.com/thequerypart`.

I'm new to nginx, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
The rest of `nginx.conf` is another `server` block that starts with:

```
server {
    server_name .com;
    ...
}
```

It works as intended without the other one.

Comment: The last `server` block in your question is the solution, but you say it captures every request. Do you have another `server` block to capture the requests for *every* hostname not ending with `.net`?

Comment: @RichardSmith edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I... didn't know browsers cache things that are "Moved permanently" (makes sense), the setup I've shown in the question worked, but a previous different attempt did not, and got cached. So, for anyone that may get here in the future, the answer is:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^(?<name>.+)\.net$";
    return 301 $scheme://$name.com$request_uri;
}
```